# Most efficient way to create CCSprites and particles in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Right now, in my game, I am spawning a sprite every second or so at the top of the screen (using a sceduler) using this code:

`The init method:`

```
[self schedule:@selector(addMeteor:) interval:1];
```

`The scheduler method:`

```
- (void)addMeteor:(ccTime)dt
{
    CCTexture2D *meteor = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"Frame3.png"];
    target = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:meteor rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 56)];
    //Rest of positioning code was here
}
```

Doing it this way causes a stutter in the frame rate every second or so (Whenever another sprite is spawned).  Is there a way to eliminate that?

Thanks in advance!

Tate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the stutter is more likely coming from other parts of the code. Do you explicitly call removeChild on meteors? That might cause a hiccup, especially with many meteors.

My advice: create N meteor sprites up front. When you need one, make it visible and change its position. When you're done with it, set it to visible = NO to make it disappear.

Comment: How would I create multiple meteors?